# Secant method optimization - initial guesses with floating point precision?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Say I want to find the root of $f(x) = e^{-x} - 5$, and assume I start with initial guesses $x_0 = -3$ and $x_1 = 3$.

I define my update function as $x_i = x_{i-1} - f(x_{i-1}) * \frac{x_{i-1} - x_{i-2}}{f(x_{i-1}) - f(x_{i-2})}$

Within a few iterations, the denominator, $f(x_{i-1}) - f(x_{i-2})$ becomes incredibly small and the entire fractional piece is on the order of $10^{-17}$.

In this case, using double precision we fail to update our $x_i$ as a subtraction with a magnitude less than $10^{-16}$ is discarded here. We then get $x_i = x_{i-1}$ due to subtracting $0$ and then fail to ever converge.

Is there some quantification of how one should choose initial guesses based on the potential of running into this? Or is there a more robust way to run the optimization that is more stable?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. You seem to want to continue at this point, but you should be more concerned with reliably detecting this situation so you can declare numerical convergence and stop the iteration. You could for instance follow the slope and break if the new one is drastically different from the old one (sign change, quotient larger 100 in either direction,...) /// Or did you mean how to restart with sensibly selected but different initial values in about the same region of interest? /// Explore Illinois regula falsi, Dekker, Muller, Brent bracketing methods

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes more about how do I choose suitable starting points to get more likely that the secant method will converge.